# Running Xcode app in not my device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a work to do in my university, we have to program an IOS app and set it to run in the Teacher's iPad Pro, I was testing to built a beta of my app today but it keeps giving it this errors:

> The operation could't be completed. Unable to log in with account
>   "myaccount@mymail.com". An unexpected failure ocurred while logging in
>   (Underlying error code -1009).
>
> Provisional profile "iOS Team Provisional Profile: com.myname.myapp"
>   doesn't include the currently selected device "My teacher's Ipad".
>
> Code signing is requiered for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS
>   10.2'

is there a way to install and run the app in my teacher's iPad?
I don't have the developer membership of Apple, because I don't want to waste 90 dlls for just and app that im not gonna be publishing on the app store.

PD: I don't have a internet conecction in the University (at the time I'm gonna install the app)
Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need a paid account but you do need a real account.

Comment: I'm using my Apple ID account

Comment: Make sure you have logged-in to XCode with your account (apple account) and haven't changed its password (if so then again login with new password). Then try installing (debugging) the app in the iPad. You must have internet connection in-order to create provisioning profile ( XCode manages it automatically).

Comment: So, its there not a problem with the iPad? I mean, it's not a problem that has annother Apple ID (my teacher's account) ?

Comment: No there is no problem with the iPad.. In order to install (debug) application on device, XCode needs provisioning profile and Code-signing certificate. Let it be your Apple ID or Teacher's Apple ID, if you have selected 'Automatically Manage Signing' for your XCode project, then XCode will attempt to create Provisioning Profile & Code-signing Certificate automatically (using Internet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PD: I don't have a internet conecction in the University (at the time I'm gonna install the app)

That's the problem. Xcode needs to register the teachers iPad onto your account in order for you to run on the iPad, and without an Internet connection it can't do that.